# Grep variable at exact point in string

Tags: bash, variables, grep

I have a file with numerical data, and reading the variables from another file extract the correct string.

I have my code to read in the variables.
The problem is the variable can occur at different points within the string, i only want the string that has the variable on the right-hand side, i.e. the last 8 characters.
e.g.

```
grep 0335439 foobar.txt

00032394850033543984  
00043245845003354390  
00060224460033543907 
00047444423700335439
```

In this case its the last line.

I have tried to write something using `${str: -8}`, but then I lose the data in front.

I have found this command

```
grep -Eo '^.{12}(0335439)' foobar.txt
```

This works, however when I use my script and put a variable in the place it doesn't, `grep -Eo '^.{12}($string)' foobar.txt`.

I have tried without brackets but it still does not work.

---

**Update:**

In this case the length of the string is always 20 characters, so counting from the LHS is OK in my case, but you are correct its was not the answer to the original question. I tried to comment the code so say this but pasting it into the comment box removed the formatting.

Comment: So you want `grep '0335439$' foobar.txt`?

Comment: no, that was just my grep command example.

Comment: I have found this command    
 grep -Eo '^.{12}(0335439)' foobar.txt        
this works, however when i use my script and put a variable in the place it doesnt,      
 <br/>
 grep -Eo '^.{12}($string)' foobar.txt       
i have tried without brackets but it still does not work.     <br/>

Comment: Of course, you need to use double quotes , `grep -Eo "^.{12}$string" foobar.txt`, otherwise, the variable expansion does not take place.

Comment: Thanks, had issues with editing the reply

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Here is full code with both solutions


    `
    #!/bin/bash
    set -x
    
    while read id; do
    echo "$id" >> id.txt
    ##n Search on the string
    ##  sentry=`grep $id /foo/largedata.txt`
    ##  match the variable from position 12 in the string
    ##  sentry=`grep -Eo "^.{12}$id" /foo/largedata.txt`
    ##  match the variable, using awk this time - took longer than the grep -Eo command
    sentry=`awk -v n=8 -v kw="$id" 'substr($0, length()-n, n) == kw' /foo/largedata.txt`
    echo $sentry >> vespa_subidawk.txt
    done <foo/bar.txt
`

Comment: Not sure dupe target is correct considering the problem statement of `i only want the string that has the variable on the right-hand side, i.e. the last 8 characters`. `"^.{12}$id"` pattern is incorrect because it assumes that there are always 20 characters in each line.

Comment: @anubhava, In this case the length of the string is always 20 characters, so counting from the LHS is OK in my case, but you are correct its was not the answer to the original question.
I tried to comment the code so say this but pasting it into the comment box removed the formatting.

Comment: Thanks @Red_badger better we put this important comment in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i only want the string that has the variable on the right-hand side, i.e. the last 8 characters

A non-regex approach using `awk` is better suited for this job:

```sh
s='00335439'
awk -v n=8 -v kw="$s" 'substr($0, length()-n, n) == kw' file

00043245845003354390
```

Here we passing `n=8` to awk and using `substr($0, length()-n, n)` we are getting last `n` characters in a line, which is then compared against variable `kw` which is set to a value on command line.